# Integrating Google Form into website

Tags: html, css, google-drive-api, google-forms

I am trying to get a Google Form integrated into my website to be used as a product order form. I have stripped the necessary parts of the Form and it successfully submits to my Google account, but I would like the form to be styled to match the "Contact Us" form built into the website. My question is: how do I integrate the styled parts into the naked Google Form?

Nicely styled html: https://codeshare.io/amOVOj

Unformatted Google Form: https://codeshare.io/5okVkp

The page is http://snotcloth.com/order.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add some extra classes to your form, both on label + input level and on the containers' one (div), so you can position and style everything easily without making it affected by the website's other stylings. Then with some CSS you can do the magic.

res: https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: That makes sense... I'm just not sure what to get rid of and what to keep! I'm adding some of the MATX (website theme) classes to the Google Form, but the formatting seems to be competing.

What is the absolute bare bones html that I need to keep the form working? If I can get rid of everything else then I should be able to format it with the existing MATX classes

Comment: Just don't get rid of anything from the form (if you have no experience), it may affect functionality. Add the extra classes and style them separately and manually (for best results) based on your website's styling or you can use other existing classes, but you might still have to work on position, line height, font, etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks Stefan! I'm experimenting with it right now and making some progress... I think I'll just keep removing and then doing a test submission to see if the form is still functioning correctly. So far it seems like the majority of the form html can be canned....

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Yeah, testing and backup are always the best.